# Wrong value JUnit5/Mockito

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

I'm new on module testing. Please, help me to find, what I'm doing wrong.

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
    List<Book> findByAuthorContainingIgnoreCase(String author);
    List<Book> findByGenreContainingIgnoreCase(String genre);
    List<Book> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

My Service:

```
public List<Book> findByAuthorContaining(String author){
        return bookRepository.findByAuthorContainingIgnoreCase(author);
}
```

And Tests:

```
    @Test
    public void findByAuthors(){
        List<Book> books = getBooks();
        Mockito.when(bookRepository.findByAuthorContainingIgnoreCase(any())).thenReturn(books);

        List<Book> result = bookService.findByAuthorContaining("testAuthor2");

        Assertions.assertEquals(1, result.size());
    }

    private List<Book> getBooks(){
        Book firstBook = new Book();
        Book secondBook = new Book();

        firstBook.setId_book(1);
        firstBook.setAmount(1);
        firstBook.setImage("/test1");
        firstBook.setGenre("testGenre");
        firstBook.setAuthor("testAuthor");
        firstBook.setYear(2001);
        firstBook.setPages(1);
        firstBook.setPrice(1);

        secondBook.setId_book(2);
        secondBook.setAmount(2);
        secondBook.setImage("/test2");
        secondBook.setGenre("testGenre2");
        secondBook.setAuthor("testAuthor2");
        secondBook.setYear(2002);
        secondBook.setPages(2);
        secondBook.setPrice(2);

        return List.of(firstBook, secondBook);
}
```

My Method findByAuthorContaining works correctly. But when I running my module test, method returns all List (2 values), regardless the value I call. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: You need to show the part of your test that creates the service and injects the mock.  Also, any annotations you have on the test class, what you have here isn't enough to determine the issue.

Comment: You're using `thenReturn(books)` which is going to return all the books. Faking the repository implementation defeats the purpose of testing anything. You should really only test your service layer since that's the only thing that should be consuming the repository.  What database are you using?

Comment: @SledgeHammer i’m using MySql DB. sooo, what data I should use? from my DB? and how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sledgehammer also mentioned in the comments, right now you are overriding the actual Spring Data JPA query and telling your mocked repository to always return back 2 books regardless (no actual query is ran against the db).

If you are trying to test that the actual query works you will need to let the repository query fetch data from an actual db (in your case MySQL but you could also use H2). With that you can get rid of the mocked repository and query your database as an integration test.

There should be plenty of examples of testing Spring Data JPA queries in integration tests.